# some containers in stl don't have find function

Tags: c++, stl, containers

Some of the STL containers such as `std::list` and `std::vector` don't have `find()` method as a member function. Why is that? I know that there is the alternative of using `std::find` from `<algorithm>` but still this use isn't 100% natural.

Comment: Probably because searching an element in sequential containres all has some algorithm, so its made common, playing around with iterators

Comment: @POW that wouldn't prevent the standard to implement `find()`, would it? I mean it could just be a call to `std::find()`...

Comment: You might want to read this [article by Steve Myers about encapsulation](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197) and this [GotW by Herb Sutter about `std::string`](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm). Basically, the more of a class's functionality you can implement outside of its direct interface, the better.

Comment: @Theolodis But there is no need to do that, or the advantages do not outweigh the disadvantages of bloating the interface. It would have been better if `std::find` could have been specialized to do the right thing for fast-look-up containers.

Comment: You've got it backwards. The versions from `<algorithm>` should be your defaults. There are special member functions only when there are special requirements.

Comment: @Theolodis Sorry, typo its _same_ not "some" [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25617610/some-containers-in-stl-dont-have-find-function#comment40020915_25617610)

Answer (score 43):

The general design principle is to use `std::find` where possible, and implement `find` member functions when it is more efficient.

The containers that *do* have a `find` member are containers which have a more efficient element look-up mechanism then the linear search performed in `std::find`. For example, binary search trees such as `std::set` and `std::map`, or hash tables such as their `unordered` counterparts.

Answer (score 13):

`find`, `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` member functions are only provided when ***more efficient*** than using the non-member equivalents, or when the ***non-members couldn't operate*** given the container's public API

Note in particular that `std::string` has a `find` function which provides `std::find()`-like linear search facilities for character searches and `std::search()`-like facilities for sub-string searches: while the non-member versions may have the same big-O efficiency, they may well be less efficient given dedicated machine code instructions are often available for "string" searching.  There are also historical, convenience, and ease-of-porting factors.

Quite apart from the question of efficiency, it's noteworthy that some containers:

- are inherently either sorted (`multi`-`set`, `map`) or unsorted (`unordered_map`, `unordered_set`), typically unsorted (e.g. `std::string`), or easily either (`std::vector`)
- publicly support forward iteration and/or random access
- possibly privately support binary search
- have such a specialised public API for element access that potential reuse of the algorithm is *relatively* limited (e.g. `unordered_map::bucket` / `::begin(n)` et al)

It's also of interest that searching in a `vector` can be done using a great many algorithms:

- `std::find` does a brute force linear O(n) search which will "find" lower-index elements first,
- `std::binary_search` requires a sorted vector but jumps around to achieve O(log2n) complexity.
- other options like extrapolation search and hashing might be applicable

How would you pick which to implement and add as members?  Seems a bit arbitrary.  Still, the choice of which to use can be important performance-wise: for a million elements, `find` averages half-a-million element comparisons before a match and the full million whenever the element's not there, while `binary_search` typically takes ~20 comparisons either way.

The containers with `find` don't typically provide such flexibility, and the `find` and/or `lower_bound`/`upper_bound` they provide can be seen as replacements for the non-member equivalents, and likely the only reasonable way to search the containers.

Answer (score 9):

Because there's the [`std::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) function from [`algorithm`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/) that applies for them.

Generally, containers like `std::vector` and `std::list` have linear search time complexity. As such attaching to them a member `find` function is a redundancy because there's already `std::find`. For other containers (e.g., `std::set` or `std::map` etc.) there's a better way (i.e., faster than linear complexity) to implement searching. As such the implementers implemented these faster searching algorithm as member functions.

Comment: OP knows this _"I know that there is the alternative of using std::find"_

Comment: Even if this is technically true, it does not really answer the question.

Comment: @MatthiasB he was using the "foot in the door" reputation gathering technique.. post a one-line answer quickly to get some upvotes and then write out the details later. *Now* it answers the question.

Comment: Since this answer answers the question, would be nice if down-voters explained the reason of their down-vote (if any...).

Answer (score 3):

Containers which have a search-by-key like feature will have the find method integrated (e.g. [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/) which is internally implemented with a binary tree which can be looked up efficiently).

Others, like the ones you cited, will allow a range search with the [std::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) but don't have a featured find function because it would have **no algorithmic advantage over the std::find** (except in sorted/special cases)

Comment: In my opinion that does not really answer the question. The answer does probably lie in the specifications...

Comment: @Theolodis the main reason has just been added and bolded

Answer (score 2):

Using the same function for various containers makes for a clearer API, you don't have to learn the peculiarities of each of the containers, just how to apply one function that you use for all of them.

It's also for code reusability - you use the algorithm that takes iterators from any of the containers that provide them, so the algorithm doesn't have to rely on the container being a `std::vector`, `std::list` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Such containers as `std::vector`, `std::list`, `std::forward_list` and some others are sequential containers. There is nothing better than sequential search that can be applied to these containers. So there is no need to rewrite the sequential search for each sequential container if it is the same for all these containers.

The exception is class `std::basic_string` that initially simulates C-strings that already have special search functions as strchr, strstr and others.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other comments, the design rationale is that `vector::find()` can be as efficiently implemented as a non-member function `std::find()`. The benefits of using the latter is that it decouples the data-structures and the operators acting on the data-structure, which increases maintainability (this is advantageous for the developers of the library).

However, the benefits of the former is that it would make the API between all containers consistent, and make client code less verbose. This would increase learnability and readability (this is advantageous for the users of the library). Also, consistent API would allow to write generic code. Consider this:

```
template <typename Container, typename T>
void foo(const Container& c, const T& x) {
    if (std::find(c.begin(), c.end(), x) != c.end()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The above is inefficient when `Container` is a `std::map` or `std::set`. To make it efficient, we'd need to do:

```
template <typename Container, typename T>
void foo(const Container& c, const T& x) {
    if (c.find(x) != c.end()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But then it doesn't compile for `std::vector` and `std::list`. This places the burden on users of the library to write their own generic function manually specialized/overloaded for each type they want to support:

```
template <typename T>
bool contains(const std::vector<T>& c, const T& x) {
    return std::find(c.begin(), c.end(), x) != c.end();
}

template <typename T>
bool contains(const std::set<T>& c, const T& x) {
    return c.find(x) != c.end();
}

template <typename Container, typename T>
void foo(const Container& c, const T& x) {
    if (contains(c, x)) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I acknowledge that making these types of design decisions is hard, but my opinion is that designers of the STL made a mistake here. The very tiny maintainability burden seems quite largely worth the better API and consistency for users. In a nutshell, since `find` must be a member function for some containers (for performance), then `find` should be a member function for all containers (for consistency). Note that I'm totally okay with other algorithms being non-member functions.

<sub>(I mean, come on, a container is by definition something that contains stuff. It should be trivial for users to write a generic and efficient "contains" function. In fact, I'd argue it should be added to the [Container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container) concept, but I digress.)</sub>